# Cannot see bitrate and other information when using iwconfig command

Tags: wireless

I just moved from win8 to ubuntu today, but had done it on a friend's computer the day before.  After setting things up, I wanted to check my wifi info, so I used iwconfig in the terminal.  This is what I got:

> ```
> wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"wifi"  
>       Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 0C:F8:93:B5:C5:B0   
>       Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>       Power Management:off
> ```

on my friend's computer, however, it showed like 2-3 more lines of info, including the bitrate. I don't know what I did to make it like this, does anyone have any idea how I can revert it?

Comment: You're not connected. Is WIFI enabled?  What wireless chip and driver do you have?

Comment: I was connected at the time, I was literally using the internet. Wifi is enabled, and I am using a broadcom 802.11n network adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to install the missing Broadcom firmware. See [community WIFI Docs for Broadcom](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx).  Exact instructions depend upon your exact Broadcom chip.